# How to re-attach old ceramic tiles?

Tags: adhesive, ceramic-tile

My house was built in 1946 (UK).  I still have the original kitchen larder.  Inside is a ?concrete plinth clad in ceramic tiles.  Some of the tiles have become detached.

How should I re-attach them?

The cement is quite thick and has taken the impression of the tiles, so I don't want to remove it as it will take a lot to built it back up and the shape means that the tiles fit perfectly.  Some of the curved tiles are also loose and will need removing and re-attaching.

Epoxy resin?  Ceramic glue?

It's quite a small area, so I want to avoid buying a tub of tile adhesive.

Also, as the fit is so good, I'm looking to use a thin layer.

[image]

Comment: Might be able to get away with silicon caulking or construction adhesive.  One tube should cover quite a bit   White silicon will kind of match the grout also.  This is for a couple/few tiles that are not walked on.

Comment: What we are seeing is likely the thinset (not sure what they call it in Blighty).  I would consider chipping some of it away before gooping the tiles back on, to a) make some room for the goop, and b) increase purchase for the goop.